# The focal length of spherical mirrors

Tags: optics, reflection, geometric-optics, lenses

How are the [focal length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focal_length), the object distance and the image distance related?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a spherical mirror, the relation between focal length, object distace and image distance is

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{f} = \frac{1}{u}+\frac{1}{v}
\end{equation}

For a lens, the corresponding formula is

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{f}=\frac{1}{v}-\frac{1}{u}
\end{equation}

The signs of $f$, $u$ and $v$ should be according to the sign convention.